# Why does "cabal sdist" not include all "files needed to build"?

Tags: haskell, cabal

According to the [wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/How_to_write_a_Haskell_program#Using_Cabal) entry,

> It packages up the files needed to build the project

I have a simple executables-only `.cabal` project, which basically contains

```
Executable myprog
  hs-source-dirs: src
  main-is: MyMain.hs
```

and is made up of some additional `.hs` files below `src/` beyond `src/MyMain.hs`. E.g., `src/Utils.hs` and a few others.

`cabal build` has no problems building `myprog`, and compiles the required additional `.hs` files below `src/`, but `cabal sdist` does not, thus creating a dysfunctional source-tarball. What am I doing wrong? How do I tell cabal to include all source files below hs-source-dirs?

As a side-note, with GNU Autotools, there was a `make distcheck` target, which would first build a source-tarball, and then try to build the project via the newly generated source-tarball, thus ensuring everything's ok. Is there something similar for `cabal`, in order to make sure my source-tarball is sound?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should list the other Haskell files in the `.cabal` file, inside the `Executable` stanza.

```
  other-modules: Utils AFewOthers
```

The distribution only includes source files that are listed in your `.cabal` file.  Cabal has no other way to detect which source files are in your package.  You could still build because `cabal build` calls `ghc --make`, and ghc will find and compile all the source files it needs.